# Xcode Debugging Limitations

Tags: xcode, ide, debugging

One of the annoyances I've faced when debugging on macs native IDE, xcode, is that the debbugers ability to read through recursive pointers - ie, a pointer pointing at a pointer pointing at a pointer pointing at data I want to read - is limited to around 4 'recurses', after which it will show the pointers structure but will show every property in as containing no data. In actual projects, these pointers are normally pointing at classes that *contain* further pointers.

This can lead to circumstances where the debugger will not display the data in std::string, will show std::vectors as empty - it has the ability to read through these natively under less complex circumstances - and other assorted issues . Before I figured this out I spent a long time trying to discern why my variables had suddenly gone blank.

This was a long time ago and I have since gotten used to it, but I feel inclined to ask about it now;

EDIT:

I am using xcode 3.2.2, I might try upgrading to the latest and see how that goes.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is this a bug in the IDE, or a limitation? Is there an options file I can modify to increase its level of inlining? Is there some apple developer page containing information on this? (I have spent some time googling)

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? I'm using Xcode Version 3.2.4 and not seeing what you're describing. Also, are you writing ObjectiveC++?

Comment: I'm using C++, do you know where I can find an upgrade to 3.2.3 / 3.2.4?

Comment: And where can you subscribe to developer updates? I'm a member at apples page but they never inform me of anything.

Comment: Did you try to get the Console to get your values? Just enter po varname

Comment: No, I didn't/haven't tried that

Comment: I'm in a bit of a rush to go somewhere now, but I'll experiment a bit when I get back.

Comment: I feel like this is probably an issue with your configuration, since I don't see why C++ code would behave differently than Obj-C code. Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Take that with a grain of salt, though, since I don't do C++.